# ButterKnife view binding in Library project for BaseFragment fails

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-library, butterknife

I am creating a library module, in which I am trying to use ButterKnife. In this module I have a BaseFragment class from which all the fragments derive. Here's the structure of the BaseFragment -

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private View mRootView;

    public BaseFragment(){}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(getLayout(), container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);
        onSetupView(mRootView);
        return mRootView;
    }

    public View getRootView() {
        return mRootView;
    }

    protected abstract void onSetupView(View rootView);
    protected abstract int getLayout();
}
```

Since it's a library project, I am using `R2` instead of `R` class for binding the views such as this -

```
@BindView(R2.id.button_selection_done)
private ImageButton mSelectionDoneButton;
```

This is done in the derived Fragment class. I have setup a debug breakpoint which is showing that none of my Views got initialized even after using BindView annotation. The IDs are correct, but it's still not working correctly. Everything works if I use `findViewById()`. Here's how I am installing ButterKnife using gradle -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

group = 'com.github.Abhi347'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Crash log

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-11 19:47:21.082 19426-19426/noob.com.noobfilechooser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: noob.com.noobfilechooser, PID: 19426
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{noob.com.noobfilechooser/com.noob.noobfilechooser.NoobFileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.noob.noobfilechooser.fragments.NoobFileFragment.turnOnMultiSelectMode(NoobFileFragment.java:177)
                                                                              at com.noob.noobfilechooser.fragments.NoobFileFragment.initializeRecyclerView(NoobFileFragment.java:84)
                                                                              at com.noob.noobfilechooser.fragments.NoobFileFragment.onSetupView(NoobFileFragment.java:70)
                                                                              at com.noob.noobfilechooser.fragments.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:24)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:604)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6340)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Is there anything I can do to make the binding work in library module too?

PS: A stable version of the library is available at github - [NoobFileChooser](https://github.com/Abhi347/NoobFileChooser), if it requires an inspection, although I am not using ButterKnife in the uploaded source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the second required include:

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

Read more about this on the [GitHub documentation page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download).

Comment: But it doesn't mention this requirement for library projects - https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects

Comment: Well, the docs for `android-apt` say *The android-apt plugin assists in working with annotation processors in combination with Android Studio.*. ButterKnife is an annotation processor. I don't see why there should be a difference between library projects and other projects. Also, the docs I linked focus on the fact that you need to use `R2` instead of `R`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. They should have had clear instructions. I am deploying this library via Jitpack, so does it mean every person using this library will have to declare apt plugin in their project level build.gradle?

Comment: I don't have any experience with library projects, so I can't really tell. I was able to answer your question just because I got the same error when using ButterKnife 8.4 :-D

Comment: Hahaha! I'll find out anyway ;-)

Comment: @noob , Where do you place the  `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0' `  ? At the  Top-level build file or module level ?

Comment: @Olal  you can check my github repo for more details, but as far as I remember, it was in the module level file. Check the repo for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment try to do binding in onViewCreated like this :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
}
```